# How to re-format or re-flash a TWRP install?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, twrp, boot-loop, htc, formatting

I was stuck in a bootloop earlier with Team Win, having just gotten an older phone.

Now I'm seeing a menu like:

```
*** Tampered ***
*** Unlocked ***
...
FASTBOOT
RECOVERY
FACTORY RESET
...
```

Selecting `FACTORY RESET` seems to get me to a stock-looking Android 4.4.3 with an HTC Sense version 6.0.

From the Android menu, selecting factory reset  gets me back to Team WIN scripts, and then back to Android well enough.  However, I previously stuck in a loop of Team WIN:

[image: team win]

This phone came with Team WIN, which is fine.  My inclination is to format and re-install as it was installed by another.  What's the general procedure?  Is it any simpler as Team WIN is already installed?

Comment: It is easier to flash custom ROMs since TWRP is installed. If you want to flash stock ROM then of course you will lose TWRP but it's the preferred way if you want to be fully sure that own the process and what goes in the phone (in which case having TWRP doesn't help)

Comment: Since I didn't install TWRP myself, it makes me a bit leery.  It **looks** quite simple:  https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-twrp/  is this changed by already having it on there?

Comment: It's upto you. You aren't comfortable so go ahead and start afresh. You may need to see how to uninstall TWRP

Comment: Also see how easy /difficult it is to flash stock ROM before deciding